# Meaning of bounds in $ \iint_{0\leq x^2+y^2\leq 4} \, dx\, dy $

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

If the bounds are written as
$$
\iint_{0\leq x^2+y^2\leq 4} \, dx\, dy
$$
What does it mean? I want the bounds written as
$$
\int_{x_\text{lower}}^{x_\text{upper}}\int_{y_\text{lower}}^{y_\text{upper}} \, dx\,dy
$$
Same for a triple integral, if
$$
\iiint_{2\leq x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 6} \, dx\,dy\,dz
$$
What is $
\int_{x_\text{lower}}^{x_\text{upper}}\int_{y_\text{lower}}^{y_\text{upper}} \int_{z_\text{lower}}^{z_\text{upper}} \, dx\,dy \,dz
$?

Thanks!

Comment: In this case, you don't even need to go to that hassle. Given a region $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, the integral $\iint_A dx\, dy$ is precisely the area of $A$. The region $A = \{ (x,y) \mid 0 \le x^2+y^2 \le 4 \}$ is precisely a closed disc of radius $2$ centred at the origin. A similar trick works for your second integral. In general, there is no reason to expect that you can decompose a multiple integral as an iteration of single integrals, unless the region of integration is particularly simple; often, you need to choose a different coordinate system (e.g. polar coordinates).

Comment: I think that you can write just one integral sign instead of two or three. An alternative way to write is just $\int_{\{\langle x,y\rangle:x^2+y^2\in[0,4]\}}\mathrm d x\mathrm d y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write $\displaystyle \int_\bullet^\bullet \int_\bullet^\bullet \cdots\, dx\,dy, $ then one integral is INSIDE the other: $\displaystyle \int_\bullet^\bullet \left( \int_\bullet^\bullet \cdots \, dx \right) \, dy.$

So the variable $y$ goes from $-2$ up to $2$, but in the INSIDE integral, for every fixed value of $y$, the other variable $x$ goes from something to something.  You have $x^2\le 4-y^2$, so $-\sqrt{4-y^2} \le x \le \sqrt{4-y^2}$.  Thus you have
$$
\int_{-2}^2 \int_{-\sqrt{4-y^2}}^{\sqrt{4-y^2}} \cdots\,dx\,dy.
$$

Comment: Thanks! For the triple integral, if $\iiint_{2\leq x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 6} \, dx\,dy\,dz$, so $x=\pm \sqrt{6-y^2-z^2}$, how can I find the values of $y$ and $z$? I want to find the form $\int_{x=-\sqrt{6-y^2-z^2}}^{\sqrt{6-y^2-z^2}}\int_{y_\text{lower}}^{y_\text{upper}} \int_{z_\text{lower}}^{z_\text{upper}} \, dx\,dy \,dz$

Answer (score 0):

It mean **Area of the disc $\mathcal D=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2\leq 4\}$.** You can change it as $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^2 r\,\mathrm d r \, \mathrm d \theta.$$

Answer (score 0):

$0 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 4$ defines a region in $\mathbb{R}^2$, specifically the closed disk centered at the origin with radius $2$.

At a given $x$, notice that $y$ ranges from $-\sqrt{4 - x^2}$ to $\sqrt{4 - x^2}$, and further $x$ can take values between $-2$ and $2$.  Therefore:

$$\iint_{0 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 4} \ dx\,dy = \int_{-2}^2 \int_{-\sqrt{4 - x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} \ dy \,dx$$

Note that the disk is symmetric in $x$ and $y$, so if you prefer, the order of integration can be swapped by everywhere replacing $x$ with $y$ and vice-versa.  I'd recommend not doing it this way though; the integral looks nicer with polar coordinates, where $0 \leq r \leq 2$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$.  **Or** we can apply Green's theorem to arrive at:

$$\iint_{0 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 4} \ dx\, dy = \frac{1}{2} \oint_C \ x\,dy - y\,dx$$
where $C$ is the circle of radius $2$ centered at the origin.

The *easiest* method for this problem, however, is recognizing that, for a given region $R \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, the integral $\displaystyle \int_R \ dx_1\,dx_2 \cdots dx_n$ gives the volume of $R$.

---

For the second integral, evaluating $\displaystyle \iiint_{2 \leq x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 6} \ dx\, dy\, dz$ is **much** easier using spherical coordinates, where we'd have $0 \leq \phi \leq \pi$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$ and $2 \leq \rho \leq 6$.  Thus:

$$\iiint_{2 \leq x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 6} \ dx\, dy\, dz = \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^\pi \int_2^6 \rho^2 \sin(\phi) \ d \rho\, d \phi\, d \theta $$

(As before, the **easiest** method would've been to calculate the volume of this region without calculus.)

Answer (score 0):

$x^2 + y^2 = 4$ is the equation for a circle with radius 2, centered at (0,0). So the bounds $x^2+y^2\le 4$ refers to the set of all points within that circle.

That means:
$$
\iint_{0 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 4} dx\, dy = \int_{-2}^2 \int_{-\sqrt{4-y^2}}^{\sqrt{4-y^2}}dx\, dy
$$

Similarly, 2 ≤ x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> + z<sup>2</sup> ≤ 8 refers to the the set of all points inside a sphere of radius 2, but outside a sphere of radius <sup>3</sup>√2. (Both spheres are centered at 0,0)

Comment: Notice that the "$0\le x^2+ y^2$' is unnecessary.  $x^2+ y^2$, for x and y real, as here, is never negative.